# Cannot connect o google cloud VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, rdp

When trying to connect to my google cloud RDP i receive an error saying that my RDP is offline when it is not. At first I thought the error was on my side, but after trying with another RDP it worked fine, any ideas?

Comment: have you checked firewall rules to ensure you can reach the machine ?

Answer (score 1):

You should first check that port 3389 is open on the GCE firewall. If not, run a command like this to create the rule $ gcloud compute firewall-rules create rdp --allow tcp:3389 --source-ranges 0.0.0.0/0 . More info is available [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/#logging_into_a_windows_virtual_machine_instance).

Here is a [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-rdp) to troubleshoot RDP issues, you can try these steps. Also you can  connect to the instance using a [serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console).